# logging to file without blocking

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a way to log to file without blocking the calling thread. still all log-calls must be executed in order.

i was thinking of something like

```
void Log(string msg)
{
    ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart ()
    {

        System.IO.File.AppendAllText("log.txt", msg);
    };
    new Thread(ts).Start();
}
```

but will this guarantee to log everything in in order?

also the Log method should be calleable from any thread at any time.

Comment: Push log messages into a queue and then have another thread that's reading from the queue to write to the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Us this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx

Then push on to the queue in order.  Have the thread pull from the Concurrent queue.  This will preserve your order.

When you log don't start a new thread for each log.  Only have one "logging" thread.

Comment: Why did it take so long for .NET to add ConcurrentQueue/BlockingCollection to its standard library? :)  Java has had BlockingQueue for nearly a decade.  .NET got it 5 months ago.  Oh well, at least it's finally here!

Comment: @MikeClark What do you mean "5 months ago"? They were there since .NET 4 (2010).

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic  You're right!  I was misinformed.  Thanks!  Now if all my clients would agree to upgrade past 3.5 I'd be all set. :-)

Comment: +1. @MikeClark - I don't see how you get "5 month ago" - since it is part of 4.0 (12 April 2010)...

Answer (score 2):

> but will this guarantee to log everything in in order?

This will log in random order. Sometime will also create `Access Denied issue` due to concurrent writes to same file.

Better way is to keep internal buffer of logs, and write out in separate single thread in a timer. This will make loss of in-memory logs(not written to file) in case of app crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't doing this for the sake of learning; you might want to consider utilizing existing logging frameworks.  There are lots of potential 'gotchas' when rolling your own and (in most cases) the logging you want has already been written.

I haven't used them all, but I can say I've never been in a situation where log4net didn't already do what I needed (and better than I would have written).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126540/what-is-your-net-logging-framework-of-choice